# C++: Params for custom rand_int function not being initialized

Tags: c++, random

I apologize in advance for the long dump of inline code, but I really couldn't find anything that wasn't relevant that I could cut out, because I don't know where exactly the problem lies.

I'm trying to make a class that handles making random numbers in a range in a simple way, but whenever I run the code, I get garbage values, probably indicating something wasn't properly initialized somewhere down the line. The trouble is that I can't find where.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// calculates a random number within a range.
class Random
{
    int x, y;
    int range;

public:

    Random() : x(0), y(1), range(1) {
        srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
    }
    ~Random() {}

    // setters and getters:
    void setX(int x) {this->x = x;}
    void setY(int y) {this->y = y;}
    void setRange(void) {this->range = (this->y - this->x) + 1;}

    int getX(void) {return this->x;}
    int getY(void) {return this->y;}
    int getRange(void) {return this->range;}

    // member functions:

    // changes negative numbers to positive.
    void absXY(void) {
        if(getX() < 0) setX(getX() * -1); // changes negative to positive.
        if(getY() < 0) setY(getY() * -1);
    }

    // swaps values around if x > y.
    void swapXY(void) {
        if(getX() > getY()) { // swaps x with y.
            int tmp = getX();
            setX(getY());
            setY(tmp);
        }
    }

    // calculates rand num and returns it.
    int getRandIntFrom(int a, int b) {
        setX(a);
        setY(b);
        setRange();
        absXY();
        swapXY();
        return getX() + (rand() % getRange());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Random r;
    if(argc == 3) {
        cout << r.getRandIntFrom((int)argv[1], (int)argv[2]) << endl;
        cout << r.getX() << endl;
        cout << r.getY() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid number of command line arguments." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've looked through this code time and again and can't see the problem.

- The PRNG was seeded and the `x`, `y`, and `range` variables were given default values in the initializer list when Random's object was created.
- The setters and getters are valid, as far as I've ever had to use them.
- The setting and getting was done inside the `getRandIntFrom()` function.
- I ran the program with the values 2 and 8, thus skipping all the code in the `absXY()` and `swapXY()` functions, so those couldn't mess that up.
- The program logic for calculating the random number itself is sound. `rand() % x` returns anywhere from `0` to `x-1`, so mod `rand()` by 1+the range and add the lower limit. Using 2 and 8, this is:

  ```
  rand() % ((8-2)+1) ->
  rand() % 7 => 0..6 ->
  2+(rand() % 7) => 2..8
  ```

Yet, when I run the program, I get garbage results every time.

```
> g++ Random.cpp -o random -Wall -std=c++11
> random 2 8
5641728
5641728
5642296
```

What could be going wrong here? I think it might have something to do with the initializer list, but that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: `(int)argv[1]` doesn't parse the first argument. It converts its pointer value to an integer. You probably want `std::stoi(argv[1])` in C++11 or `std::strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10)` in pre-C++11.

Comment: g++ I guess doesn't recognize stoi, it gives errors. 'Undeclared', and 'not a member of std'

Comment: `-std=c++11` should mitigate that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the command line arguments you are Casting a c-string to an integer. What you get is the address where the command line argument is stored. So also your Random class returns values matching this address + the given range. Instead of the cast you could use atoi() Change the main function to.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Random r;
    if (argc == 3) {
        cout << r.getRandIntFrom(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])) << endl;
        cout << r.getX() << endl;
        cout << r.getY() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid number of command line arguments." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

AlexD was faster

Comment: I wouldn't really have wanted to use atoi because it isn't such a safe function to use, but it did work for my program. I think there could be a better string converting function out there, though.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere did you even look at the comments on the other answer? if your compiler doesn't recognize `stoi`, you still have `strtol()`…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I did look at those comments. `strtol` is deprecated and gives me compiler warnings, so I'm not using it. I ended up using string streams and the problem is fixed.

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere If your implementation of C++ marks `strtol()` as deprecated, then your implementation is unfortunately full of crap and you should throw it away ASAP. `strtol()` is **most certainly** not "deprecated". Is your compiler shipped by Microsoft by any chance? Those guys have this funny habit of randomly marking arbitrary stdlib functions as "deprecated".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry, that was my mistake, I worded that wrong. It's not deprecated, I just misunderstood the warning. "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*", because I set the middle arg to an empty string. That's me being stupid, disregard.

Answer (score 1):

Strings cannot be converted to integers with cast:

```
r.getRandIntFrom((int)argv[1], (int)argv[2])
```

Consider `std::stoi()` or alike instead:

```
try
{
    cout << r.getRandIntFrom(std::stoi(argv[1]), std::stoi(argv[2]) << endl;
    cout << r.getX() << endl;
    cout << r.getY() << endl;
}
catch (std::invalid_argument&)
{
    cout << "invalid argument\n";
    return -1;
}
catch (std::out_of_range&)
{
    cout << "out of range\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: don't recommend `atoi`, it's broken and dangerous. if any alternative, `strtol()` and/or `std::stoi()` are to be preferred.

Comment: "error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope."
"error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'"

Comment: @DylanLaCoursiere Do you have `#include <string>`? (But it could be that your compiler is not up to date. See **TheParamagneticCroissant**'s comment regarding `strtol`.)

Comment: @AlexD I do have `string`. `strtol` works, but is deprecated and gives a warning, so I won't use it. I actually solved my problem with string streams in the end.